# I need to figure out converting user input to make a simple case-sensitivity calculator with only 1 floating point

Tags: python, cs50

## **What I need is, am I doing correct? If not where to look at this to solve this problem.**

CS50 Python Math Interpreter problem by converting user input to make a simple case-sensitive calculator.
It is case-sensitive because I want to use .split(" ") to store the inputs seperatly so I can use them later in the code.

It is suggested in the probelm to use 'x, y, z = expression.split(" ")'
Let user enter an expression

- x and z is an integer
- y is a +, -, *, or /
  Should have one floating point 00.0
  For excample if the user inputs 1 + 1, your program should output 2.0. Assume that, if y is /, then z will not be 0.

I first tried this one, but I'm not sure even I'm doing the correct thing by using .format()

```
simp_arithmetic = input("Expression: ")
x, y, z = simp_arithmetic.split(" ")

if '+' in simp_arithmetic:
    print(simp_arithmetic.format(x + z))

elif '-' in simp_arithmetic:
    print(simp_arithmetic.format(x - z))

elif '*' in simp_arithmetic:
    print(simp_arithmetic.format(x * z))

elif '/' in simp_arithmetic:
    if z == '0':
        print("z can't be 0")
    else:
        print(simp_arithmetic.format(x / z))
else:
    print(" ")
```

After this, I changed the format()
`print(simp_arithmetic.format(int(x) + int(z))),`
or
`print(simp_arithmetic.format(int:x + int:z))`

And I was expeting a out come like 1 + 1 = 2.0 or similar to this but my program only returns the given value in addition.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Comment: str.format is not what you need here. You should take a look at f-strings. You also need to do a **lot** of validation if you want this to be robust

Comment: I would use an f-string, which enables calculation within the string, e.g., the print statement for + could be modified to `print(f"{simp_arithmetic} = {float(x)+float(z)}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which wrapped my suggestion of using f-strings in a more object-oriented way. Note that the zeroDivision-Error is handled by python itself and is therefore not checked manually.

```
class SimpleArithmethic():

    def __init__(self, expression):
        self._expression = expression
        _parts_of_calculation = simp_arithmetic.split(" ")

        if len(_parts_of_calculation) != 3:
            self.error()

        self._first_value = float(_parts_of_calculation[0])
        self._second_value = float(_parts_of_calculation[2])
        self._arithmetic = _parts_of_calculation[1]

    @staticmethod
    def error():
        raise ValueError("input not in the correct format please use %f %s %f")

    def calculate(self):
        match self._arithmetic:
            case "+":
                self.addition()
            case "-":
                self.subtraction()
            case "*":
                self.multiplication()
            case "/":
                self.division()
            case _:
                self.error()

    def addition(self):
        print(f"{self._expression} = {self._first_value+self._second_value}")

    def subtraction(self):
        print(f"{self._expression} = {self._first_value-self._second_value}")

    def division(self):
        print(f"{self._expression} = {self._first_value/self._second_value}")

    def multiplication(self):
        print(f"{self._expression} = {self._first_value*self._second_value}")




simp_arithmetic = input("Expression: ")
simple_arithmetic = SimpleArithmethic(simp_arithmetic)
simple_arithmetic.calculate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator module is ideal for this. You can construct a dictionary which maps the operators to their corresponding functions.

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

FMAP = {
    "+": add,
    "-": sub,
    "*": mul,
    "/": truediv
}

expression = input("Expression: ")
try:
    x, op, y = expression.split()
    result = FMAP[op](float(x), float(y))
    print(f"{expression} = {result}")
except KeyError:
    print("Invalid operator")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Or, if you prefer to wrap the functionality in a class then:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv


class SimpleArithmetic:
    FMAP = {"+": add, "-": sub, "*": mul, "/": truediv}

    def __init__(self, expression):
        self._expression = expression

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            x, op, y = self._expression.split()
            result = self.FMAP[op](float(x), float(y))
            return f"{self._expression} = {result}"
        except KeyError:
            return "Invalid operator"
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)


expression = input("Expression: ")
print(SimpleArithmetic(expression))
```